# GROUP a result of JOINS using QUERY BUILDER in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, builder

I have the following function, the params are "asc,PV1"

```
public function get_products($order, $sku){
    if(is_array($result) && $result['active']){
        $id_emp = $result['id_emp'];
        $mts = 'module_tienda_status';
        $mtc = 'module_tienda_categories';
        $mtp = 'module_tienda_productos';
        $mtpt = 'module_tienda_product_type';
        $mtpa = 'module_tienda_product_attribute';
        $mta = 'module_tienda_attributes';
        $mtao = 'module_tienda_attribute_option';
        $mtpv = 'module_tienda_product_variation';
        $mtpvo = 'module_tienda_product_variation_options';
        $get = array(
            $mtp.'.id',
            $mtp.'.name',
            $mtp.'.sku',
            $mtp.'.desc_short',
            $mtp.'.desc_long',
            $mtp.'.id_category',
            $mtp.'.price',
            $mtp.'.id_status',
            $mtp.'.inventory',
            $mtp.'.imgs',
            $mtp.'.qty',
            $mtp.'.featured',
            $mtc.'.name as cat_name',
            $mtpt.'.id as type_id',
            $mtpa.'.id_attribute',
            $mtpa.'.id_option',
            $mta.'.name as attr_name',
            $mtao.'.option as opt_name',
            $mtpv.'.inventory as var_inv',
            $mtpv.'.qty as var_qty',
            $mtpv.'.price as var_price',
            $mtpvo.'.id_product_variation as var_id',
            $mtpvo.'.id_attribute as var_attr',
            $mtpvo.'.id_option as var_opt'
        );
        $this->db->select($get);
        $this->db->from($mts);
        $this->db->join($mtp, $mtp.'.id_status = '.$mts.'.id');
        $this->db->join($mtc, $mtp.'.id_category = '.$mtc.'.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join($mtpt, $mtp.'.id_product_type = '.$mtpt.'.id');
        $this->db->join($mtpa, $mtpa.'.id_product = '.$mtp.'.id', 'left');
        $this->db->join($mta, $mta.'.id = '.$mtpa.'.id_attribute', 'left');
        $this->db->join($mtao, $mtao.'.id = '.$mtpa.'.id_option', 'left');
        $this->db->join($mtpv, $mtp.'.id = '.$mtpv.'.id_product', 'left');
        $this->db->join($mtpvo, $mtpv.'.id = '.$mtpvo.'.id_product_variation', 'left');
        $this->db->where($mtp.'.id_emp', $id_emp);
        if($sku != 'null'){
            $this->db->where($mtp.'.sku', $sku);
        }
        if(!is_null($order)){
            $this->db->order_by('module_tienda_productos.created', $order);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    }else{
        return $result;
    }
}
```

the result is an array with 49 rows of the same product, the difference is that there are different attributes and variations, here is the example https://pastebin.com/3X4w6wEi

What i want is 1 single result with an array of attributes and 1 array of variations something like this (is a json, please decode it)

```
[{'id':'343','name':'Producto variable 1','sku':'PV1','desc_short':'<p><br></p>','desc_long':'<p><br></p>','id_category':null,'price':null,'id_status':'1','inventory':'0','imgs':null,'qty':'0','featured':'0','cat_name':null,'type_id':'2','attributes':[{'id_attribute':'49','attr_name':'Colors','opts':{'107':'Amarillo','110':'Celeste','121':'Rojo','122':'Azul'}},{'id_attribute':'57','attr_name':'Size','opts':{'112':'xs','113':'s','114':'n','116':'xl'}}],'variations':[{'var_id':'42','var_inv':'0','var_qty':'0','var_price':'0.00','opts':[{'id_attribute':'49','attr_name':'Colors','opts':{'107':'Amarillo','110':'Celeste','121':'Rojo','122':'Azul'}},{'id_attribute':'57','attr_name':'Size','opts':{'112':'xs'}}]}]}]
```

Comment: have you tried Object Serialization - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: You need to run two queries instead of this multiple join query. First to get all product data and second for all attributes and then you can get it as you wanted format.

Comment: Thank the idea of running two separate queries have helped me, thank you